# HTML5 (Bootstrap): Display "floating" error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am busy creating admin panels. These admin panels include various tables, modals and dialogs and submit data via AJAX. When the server encounters an error it sends the error back as the "data" to the AJAX request which must then be displayed. I am looking for a way to display the error message "floating" on the screen for a few seconds. This must pop up on top of everything on the screen (including open modals).

One way to do this is a javascript alert, but this is not user/mobile friendly. Another way is through a modal/dialog, but this does not work if a modal/dialog is already open. In short, I am looking for a way to display a "floating div" in the center of the screen, no matter where on the page the user has scrolled to or what modals/dialogs are open at that time.

Comment: Why are alerts not mobile friendly?

Comment: Hi Markus, I have had issues, specifically on iPads where javascript alert and prompt does not work properly. Additionally, it's more a case of styling. Javascript alerts just does not look nice and cannot be faded in and out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create an element inside your ajax response callback:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your-script.php",
  done: function(response) {
    // set the message to display: none to fade it in later.
    var message = $('<div class="alert alert-error error-message" style="display: none;">');
    // a close button
    var close = $('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times</button>');
    message.append(close); // adding the close button to the message
    message.append(response); // adding the error response to the message
    // add the message element to the body, fadein, wait 3secs, fadeout
    message.appendTo($('body')).fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
  }
});
```

And the CSS:

```
.error-message {
    position: fixed;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Adjust the z-index to bring the message to the front.

Comment: Hi Markus, thank you for your reply. I have not yet implemented your code and I am going to try it now. As there is lots of functionality on a single page (creating users, creating accounts, linking users to accounts, modifying users/accounts, etc), I'm concerned about creating this element every time. Also, I'm concerned that the errors will be concatenated. Is there a way to do to define this element once and simply update the message and then show/hide (note, it is important that is pops up in the center over anything currently on the screen).

Comment: Your advice worked, thank. I have modified it a little to have one HTML element that I change the content of whenever I need to display an error message, but it is showing nicely centered and on top of everything.

Comment: In case someone is wondering why the close button does not work... "data dismiss" in the button declaration should have a hyphen: "data-dismiss". So the line should read: var close = $('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times</button>');